# cuFFT profiling issue

Tags: cuda, nvidia, cufft

I am trying to get the profiling data for cuFFT library calls for example plan and exec. I am using nvprof (command line profiling tool), with option of "--print-api-trace". It prints the time for all the apis except the cuFFT apis. Is there a any flag i need to change to get the cuFFT profiling data ? 
Or 
I need to use the events and measure myself ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the nvprof [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html#nvprof-overview), [api-trace-mode](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html#gpu-trace-and-api-trace-modes):

> API-trace mode shows the timeline of all CUDA runtime and driver API calls

cuFFT is neither the [CUDA runtime API](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/index.html) nor the [CUDA driver API](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/index.html).   It is a library of routines for FFT, whose documentation is [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cufft/index.html).

You can still use either nvprof, the command line profiler, or the visual profiler, to gather data about how cuFFT uses the GPU, of course.

Answer (score -2):

Got it working.. Instead of using the nvprof i used the CUDA_PROFILE environment variable.

Comment: Specifying CUDA_PROFILE not only fails to resolve your question but it enables a completely different tool. None of the NVIDIA profiling tools support tracing the cuFFT CPU API calls. All of the tools can be enabled to trace the CUDA kernel launches initiated by cuFFT.

Comment: thanks all for the clarification.. but could u please share where i can get the what CUDA_PROFILE does? and how it does ?

Comment: (CUDA command line profiler)[http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html#compute-command-line-profiler-overview]. The CUDA command line profiler is built into the CUDA driver. nvprof, a new command line profiler, was released in CUDA 5.0 and provides significantly more features than the previous CUDA command line profiler.